# Download file from ADLGen2 to local server using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to download ADLGen2 file to my local server using ADF.

I tried to set up self hosted integration run-time, but I am getting below error

***the integration runtime (self-hosted) node has encountered an error during registration***

The account through which I have logged into my azure portal and the account which has access on my local machine are completely different.

**Azure Portal login** : xyz_abc@gmail.com

**Local machine login**: officiallogin@companyname

Is the issue because of 2 completely different logins

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Raksha

Comment: Can you show us what is your error message?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "`The account through which I have logged into my azure portal and the account which has access on my local machine are completely different`", make sure to uninstall and re-install the self-hosted integration runtime manually choosing the **option2**.

**OR**

You may try to uninstall the current self-hosted integration runtime. Maybe you can try the **Option1**. It will install and register the integration runtime automatically.

[image]

**Reference:** [Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime).